# DJI F450 ESC calibration fail

Tags: quadcopters, esc, troubleshooting, dji

everyone. I am building a DJI F450 clone. I've got everything attached except for the propellers. The Pixhawk connects to my mission planner via USB. The remote controller is paired with the drone. Now I need to calibrate my ESB. Unfortunately, this is not working. The drone seems not to be going into calibration mode. It just blinks yellow and beeps.

Here is a video of the issue: https://youtu.be/t6_HZAf62zw

Potential problems and fixes I've tried:

1. PWM vs PPM on the remote. I've tried it both ways, with no luck.
2. Power connection is backwards. In the tutorial I'm following, the connections seem to be a bit different from my hardware. I've got a female XT60 on my shield, a male XT60 on the battery, a male XT60 on the "in" side of my power board and a female on the "out" side (the one which also has the data cable coming out of it.) The only way I can plug this thing together is to plug the battery into the "out" side of the power board and the shield into the "in" side, as seen in the video above. To test this hypothesis, I made some female-female and male-male jumper cables and tried to connect things the way they are on the tutorial...but no luck, same result.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the FS-i6, it was my first radio. The throttle is generally on the left, and it is generally mode 2. In your case, it doesn't appear to be the case. So it might be useful to check in the transmitter settings if you have channel assigned correctly.

You can always see the signals sent to the FC in the Mission planner Setup tap under RC calibration. Ensure throttle signal moves as you desire.

From what I can see, there is probably some issue with the RC link and the signal being sent to the Pixhawk.

Answer (score -1):

what don't you make a panel board within each propellers.
then give exact amount for each wing = Esb via pixhawk programme.

how to control?
1.try braille code instead of single unit code.

i would make the battery at the centre.wired it along the route toward propellers.why? : coz batteries and ppm in the centre will effect the signal divide for each propellers.
that why u dont get syno caliph for each propellers.